# He pressed back button closes my application windows phone 8.1

Tags: vba, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I navigate from Page1.xaml to Page2.xaml by using a button with the click event code:

Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage1))

When I am on Page2, and I use the hardware back button the app closes without an exception or anything. It just returns to the startscreen.

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

Kind regards, Antonio

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are created blank page. Create basic page you will not get this problem.